# Code for A room function reservation spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I just came for some guidance on how to display a booking sheet that i can glance at when looking at availability.  In the format Dates along the top and Rooms along the side.

I've taken a small chunk of the Booking list to test upon, can anyone help. In the Availability sheet the Date I want to test on is 01/01/2018 or D3 and the function room number is 1 or C5.

In the Booking list sheet I want to check all the Booking to see if any fit into this time /room slot so the "Check In" list is H30:H37 and the "check out" column is I30:I37. Lastly the room number list is G30:G37. 
Just to clarify I need a statement that will show ""Booked" if booked or "Free" if open.

I have repeatedly attempted IF AND SUM PRODUCT,HLOOKUP AND VLOOKUP but none seem to match my needs:

```
IF(AND(D3=H30:H37, D3<=I30:I37, D5=G30:G37),"BOOKED,"OPEN")
```

Can anyone point me in right direction or give me some code to attempt?

Comment: I have attempted my own code which goes as is, IF(AND(D3=H30:H37, D3<=I30:I37, D5=G30:G37),"BOOKED,"OPEN")

Comment: You will have to separate the list of Rooms in a dedicated table in order to check if all the rooms are taken at your selected date. Then you'll have to do some calculations ... Can you try to upload a file in that way so we can help you ?